# Is this user authentication process reasonable?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I've been developing RESTful API server communicating with cross-platform clients such as Android, iOS, Web browser, and so on.

When a user login successfully by username and password, this server issue an access token(JWT, 5 minutes) and a refresh token(GUID, 20 days).

When we develop Android client app communicating with server, we just can store this tokens in mobile device and I believe it will not be a problem in terms of security( using `SharedPreferences`).

But when it comes to Web browsers, (React App) I had to tackle where to store these tokens. Finally, I decided `HttpOnly Cookie`, because I can manage easily CSRF attacks rather than XSS.

Soon, I doubt this is a typical design. For example, web browser users cannot logout whenever they want. So I determinate change the wrapper server(Node.js) between the React app and the RESTful API server.

In my second design, the React App and the wrapper server authenticate session-cookie model, using `passport.js` for exmaple. And when the wrapper recognize the request is authenticated, then the wrapper issue a short term access token(1 minute JWT) and reorganize the request by inserting the access token just issued in the header sent to the RESTful API server.

Is this reasonable process? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your solution by removing the JWT access token altogether. The refresh token could be used as a session id. Every time a client issues an API call to the server the session id is sent in an HTTP header, so you can check if the request is legitimate.

Your approach of using a JWT token with a short expiration time is ok, but it brings some complexity to your system. In my opinion this approach is best suited for systems where you have an authentication service and a resource owner service. So the client would request an access token to the authentication service and use that token to communicate with the resource owner service. Then the resource owner can check the validity of the access token by just checking whether the signature matches the authentication service's.

I hope this helps you, let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I've already operated 2 or 3 API services seperate from authentication service. And theses services sometimes check the validity of the access token...